# Unable to solve $ \int \frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1} dx $?

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

This comes from a bigger problem :- 
$$ \text{Evaluate } \int\frac{dx}{1+x^4} $$

After making $ \int \frac {dx}{1+x^4} = \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2 - (\sqrt{2}x)^2} $ and then applying partial fraction method, I got :-

$$ \int \frac{dx}{1 + x^4} =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \int \frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1} dx - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \int \frac{x - \sqrt{2}}{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1} dx $$

Now, to the first integral, I tried making a u-substitution:-

$$ \text{Let }x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1 = u \\
\frac{du}{dx} = 2x + \sqrt{2} \\
\implies du = (2x + \sqrt{2}) dx \\ $$

As you can see, it is not the same as the numerator, which is $$ (x + \sqrt{2}) dx $$

Any hints on how to proceed ?

Comment: Now we can try to open this topic. +1 for editing.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1724628/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2434251/11619) are nearly equally good duplicate targets. There are undoubtedly better ones, but it is not my job to look for them. Anyway, this horse has been beaten to death. Downvotes to all trusted users who fail to realize this. Newbies are excused.

Comment: @arandomguy: you mentioned a "bigger" problem in your post. Does that serve simply a motivation to your question in the title or is that the real question you want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+\sqrt2 = \frac{1}{2}(2x+2\sqrt2) = \frac{1}{2}(2x+\sqrt2)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2$

Let $x^2+\sqrt2 \ x+1 = t \implies (2x+\sqrt2)dx = dt $

So, the integral is

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{t}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+\sqrt 2 \ x+1)}$$

The first part gets evaluated into $\frac{1}{2}\ln t$. Convert the second part into $u^2+ a^2$ form which gets evaluated into $\frac{1}{a}\arctan(\frac{u}{a})$

Answer (score 3):

The hint:
$$\frac{x+\sqrt2}{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}=\frac{x+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}$$ and use $\ln$ and $\arctan$.

Comment: (+1) nice .......

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have $$x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1=\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{x+\sqrt{2}}{x^2+\sqrt2 x+1}=\frac{x+\sqrt{2}}{\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2+\frac12}$.

Let $\displaystyle x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2=\frac{\sqrt2}2\tan\theta$.